# Mat-card are overlapping 80 procent of the time

Tags: html, css

I have around 16 mat cards and I want 4 on each row and when I resize the screen I don't want the cards to become smaller. I want to reduce the number of cards on each row when resizing so the cards dont overlap.
But for some reason, my cards overlap 80 procent of the times but sometimes they don't overlap and just move to another row and that is exactly what i want. Does anybody know a solution to make the cards not overlap 100% of the time?

Answer (score 0):

You need to write each card in `mat-grid-list` and `cols="4"`. Also you can see reference at angular material official website.

[angular material official website](https://material.angular.io/components/grid-list/overview)

If you don't want to use this for layout than you can use bootstrap for layout.

[bootstrap layout](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/layout/grid/)